# Failure in performing update and upgrade on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I am new to Raspbian. I have a Raspberry Pi3 Model B.

I am trying to interface RTC DS1307 with it.

The steps outlined in the documentation are:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade

When I perform the ***step 1.***, 
I get the following errors:

```
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
99% [1 InRelease gpgv 197 B] [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_stretch_InRelease into data Err http://repo.mysql.com stretch InRelease

99% [2 InRelease gpgv 197 B] [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_InRelease Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InReleasept/lists/partial/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_InRelease into data and signature failed

Fetched 591 B in 5s (112 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com stretch InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http//mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/rasp ... /InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/ ... /InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/d ... /InRelease

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I perform ***step 2.***, I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python3 (3.4.2-2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.4...
dpkg-query: package 'gdebi-core' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gdebi-core
error running python rtupdate hook gdebi-core
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.4.2-2); however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3
python3-dev
dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

May I know where I am going wrong? Or what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is something broken with your apt list files. You can try to reinitialize them. Edit this two files:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Note what lines does not have a `#` at first character. Set it and save the files. Then do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

Because there are no entries in *sources.list* and *raspi.list* (they are all commented), all list files for the repositories will be removed. Now edit the two files again and remove the `#` you have set, but only that. Now do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Don't know if that helps but it is worth a try.

Comment: Ha ha - you and I keep bumping into each other trying to answer the same questions :)  As usual, you are on the right track... OP clearly has a conflict with his sources list. Note that `stretch` and `jessie` are both mentioned in the first 3 lines of his terminal record.

Comment: @Seamus Yes - with your short time I like to disburden you a bit ;-))